# Protobuffers and Golang --- writing out marshal'ed structs and reading back in

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, grpc-go, protobuf-go

Is there a generally accepted "correct" way for writing out and reading back in marshaled protocol buffer messages from a file?

I've been working on a smaller project that simulates a full network locally with gRPC and am trying to add writing to/ reading from files s.t. I can save state and start from there when its launched again. It seems I was naive in assuming these would remain on a single line:

```
Sees chain of length 3
```

from debugging messages I've written; but,

```
$ wc test.dat
   7    8 2483 test.dat
```

So, I suppose there are an extra 4 newline's... Is there a method of delimiting these that I can use? or do I need to come up with one on my own? I realize this is straightforward, but in my mind, I can only probabilistically guarantee that `<<<<DELIMIT>>>>` or whatever will never show up and put me back at square 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use proto.Marshal/Unmarshal:

That way you simulate (closest) to receiving the message while avoiding side effects from other Marshal methods.

Alternative: Dump it as []byte and reread it.

Comment: Ah I should have been clearer/ posted code... that's what I've got, tried initially prepending some extra things for me to reconstruct the data structure wrappers with certainty and then cut down to just `proto.Marshal` and `proto.Unmarshal`; to be clear, my issue *seems* to be that the marshal'ed messages contain newline characters (not unrealistic... if I open in e.g. Vim even with a Nerd font, etc., still lots of question mark square char's/ rune's)

Comment: The marshalled data is []byte, so this might happen on byte alignment